# ng-if or ng-class inside a string that translate into HTML

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

This is a simple directive gets string that can be also html (I use html pipe so it is working fine):

```
<div [my-directive]="'any string...'"></div>
```

Also this will render fine:

```
<div [my-directive]="'<div style=\'color:red;\'></div>'"></div>
```

and also that will work great:

```
<div [my-directive]="'<div>{{object.value}}</div>'"></div>
```

BUT if I will add ng-if or ng-class that will not work:

```
<div [my-directive]="'<div ng-if=\'object.value === \'OK\' \'></div>'"></div>
```

and I don't understand why. Why {{ }} will render, but ng-* will not.

The directive component takes the string and insret it as innerHTML:

```
template: <div [innerHTML]="htmlStr"></div>
```

the htmlStr is `SafeHtml`.

Comment: Read more about `property bindings` and `structural directives` in angular

Comment: Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: first of all you question is not clear and if u r using angular2  `*ngIf` must be used